# Sorting a ReactTable based on a Switch being active

Tags: reactjs

I need to sort a react table with the rows where a Switch is checked appearing at the top.

[image: sorted by active first]

Here is the code I have so far.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactTable from 'react-table';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Switch } from '@material-ui/core';

import * as Actions from 'app/routes/actions/store/actions';
import { Pagination, FilterCaseInsensitive } from 'app/library';

export const PromotionControl = (props) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const model = props.model;
    const setModel = props.setModel;
    const pageState = props.pageState;
    const promotions = props.promotions;

    function hasPromotion(promotion) {
        if (model.actionPromotions === undefined)
            return false;

        const exists = model.actionPromotions.find(t => t.clientPromotionId === promotion.clientPromotionId);
        return exists !== undefined;
    }

    function handlePromotionSelection(promotion) {
        let selectedPromotions;

        if (hasPromotion(promotion)) {
            selectedPromotions = model.actionPromotions.filter(t =>
                t.clientPromotionId !== promotion.clientPromotionId
            );
        }
        else {
            selectedPromotions = [...model.actionPromotions, {
                clientPromotionId: promotion.clientPromotionId,
                promotionName: promotion.promotionName
            }];
        }
        setModel(values => ({ ...values, actionPromotions: selectedPromotions }));
    }

    return props.promotions.length <= 0 ? (<h5>No promotions configured.</h5>) : (
        <React.Fragment>
            <ReactTable
                data={promotions}
                PaginationComponent={Pagination}
                defaultPageSize={5}
                className="-striped -highlight"
                minRows={0}
                filterable={pageState.filterable}
                sortable
                filtered={pageState.filtered}
                defaultFilterMethod={FilterCaseInsensitive}
                onFilteredChange={(filtered) => dispatch(Actions.filterPromotions(filtered))}
                columns={[
                    {
                        Header: "Client Promotion ID",
                        accessor: 'clientPromotionId',
                        width:200
                    },
                    {
                        Header: "Type",
                        accessor: 'promotionType',
                        maxWidth: 300
                    },
                    {
                        Header: "Name",
                        accessor: "promotionName"
                    },
                    {
                        maxWidth: 70,
                        style: { justifyContent: 'center' },
                        Cell: item => {
                            return (
                                <Switch
                                     checked={hasPromotion(item.original)}
                                     onClick={() => handlePromotionSelection(item.original)}
                                />
                            )
                        }
                    }
                ]}
            />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

The column I want to sort the table by is the last column. At the moment the switch is checked based on the result of a check performed by the hasPromotion function. The issue is I don't know how to sort the whole table based on this column with the checked ones appearing at the top of the table.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As in Javascript, we have :

```
true - false === 1
false - true === -1
```

You could just base your sort on these values :

```
yourDataMatrix = yourDataMatrix.sort((a,b) => b.values[indexOfColumnToSort] - a.values[indexOfColumnToSort]);
```

Since I don't know the structure of your data, this code is not working, but you can use the logic in your code